# How to cast PropertyInfo to MyCustomPropertyInfo?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, propertyinfo

I have my own custom `PropertyInfo`:

```
Public MustInherit Class MyCustomPropertyInfo
Inherits PropertyInfo

'... Some Added Properties 

End Class
```

In another class i try to retrieve it:

```
Dim MyActualProperty As MyCustomPropertyInfo = Me.GetType.GetProperty("SomeProperty")
```

But it gives me this exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'RuntimePropertyInfo' to type
>   'MyCustomPropertyInfo'

Comment: You can't cast to something that the object is not. A `RuntimePropertyInfo` is **not** a `MyCustomPropertyInfo` so you simply cannot cast it as one.

Comment: I need a workaround how to extend functionality of the propertyinfo class to add more information to my properties, it is necessary.

Comment: What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve by extending `PropertyInfo`?

Comment: I need add a state to each property wich set and get a value that indicates whether it is correct or no, being binded to textblocks's text for each control that represent to the properties. state's value is set through these controls onpropertychanged...

Comment: Don't do that by extending a `PropertyInfo` as that's static to the type. You're dealing with instances of objects so you should just create a adapter class that has the require boolean properties that you can instantiate and wrap each instance you are tracking.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround how to solve my question adding a property's state to each property in the same class and not within each PropertyInfo, because as says Enigmativity I can't do that by extending a PropertyInfo as that's static to the type, I am dealing with instances of objects.

Public Class Person

Private _Name As String

Public Property Name As String
'Get/Set

Private _NameSTATE As Boolean

Public Property NameSTATE As Boolean
'Get/Set

'... More Properties With States

End Class

Thanks to Enigmativity for the clarification...